# How can I customize my sign up custom policy in azure b2c?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I used this documentation to separate email verification from account creation:
[Separate the Email Verification and User Registration into 2 separate screens](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/split-email-verification-and-signup)

This the result :
[Custom sign up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7owpr.png)

I changed some labels and create buton in localization file, but now I need to know how to add text to my page as shown in the attached images. Is it feasible with XML? if not please how to do it?

[Customiszation needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMyuk.png)

**UPDATE :**
Do I have to make my own html/css customization and change de LoadUri of contentdeifinition Id="api.localaccountsignup" to use my cshtml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can [customise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) it.

You make your own HTML/CSS, upload to blob storage and then point to blob storage from the XML file.

You can also add your own [JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

Comment: Just to confirm if I understood the documentation correctly. For example, do I have to insert my html code inside the <div id="api" tag ></div> insert my html code to add the text before the email, then make an input with the same id of the custom policy claimtype and so on? or should I do otherwise?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#custom-html-page-content

Comment: "Your custom page content can contain any HTML elements, including CSS and JavaScript, but cannot include insecure elements like iframes. The only required element is a div element with id set to api, such as this one <div id="api"></div> within your HTML page." The div element is where B2C inserts the login page. Suggest you work through the example in the link I posted.

Comment: Ok thank you @rbrayb

Comment: I am still confused, I understand that I can change the style of the custom policy's content with css, but how do I add text? is it with javascript?

Comment: It's fine, there is a sample code in js for adding checkbox for showing or hiding password.
Thanks for help